# How do I make my program run only the second output?

Tags: java, loops

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Chapter10_NextGeneration {
public static void main(String[]args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in your cell positions(ie 8,A,D,D,A,D,D,A,A,2 - NO SPACES & CASE SENSITIVE): ");
    String positions_str=sc.nextLine();
    sc.close();
    String[] cells=positions_str.split(",");
    String[] next_generation=new String[cells.length-2];x
    for(int j=0; j < Integer.parseInt(cells[cells.length-1]); j++) {
    for(int i=1;i<cells.length-1;i++) {
        if(i-1<1) { 
            if(cells[i+1].equals("D")) {
                next_generation[i-1]="D";
            }
            else {
                next_generation[i-1]="A";
            }
        }
        else if(i+1==cells.length-1) {
            if(cells[i-1].equals("D")) {
                next_generation[i-1]="D";
            }
            else {
                next_generation[i-1]="A";
            }
        }
        else if((cells[i-1].equals("A") && cells[i+1].equals("D")) || (cells[i-1].equals("D") && cells[i+1].equals("A"))) {
                next_generation[i - 1]="A";
            }
        else if((cells[i-1].equals("A") && cells[i+1].equals("A")) || (cells[i-1].equals("D") && cells[i+1].equals("D"))) {
                next_generation[i - 1]="D";
            }
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < next_generation.length; i++) {
            cells[i+1]=next_generation[i];
            System.out.print(next_generation[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm having trouble getting my program to only print the final output. When my input is `8,A,D,D,A,D,D,A,A,2`, the output is supposed to be `AAADADDA`, but the program prints `DAADAAAAAAADADDA`. The 2 at the end of the input runs the program 2 times, but all I want is the output when it is run the second time. How do I make the program not print the first time the my input is run?

Here's a visual:
[Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PPas.png)

All I want is the part highlighted in blue. I don't want the part that is not highlighted. What should I do?

Comment: You could just set the case of the input and you wouldn't need to worry about it being case sensitive.  And it would really help if you were to add a few comments explaining what the code is doing (if you know-it looks like you typed it from a book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your loop that prints is inside the for loop that runs twice. So it will print the first time and the second one. You need to move the print statement out of the nested loops and run a loop after all the others are finished to print the values

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I only want the output when it is run the second time, sir.

Comment: I don't want the first output to print witht the second one, sir

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to print out the state of ```next_generation``` after running the substitution part twice?

Comment: boi yeet Moritz answer is correct.  You have your output generator inside the loop  for(int j=0; j < Integer.parseInt(cells[cells.length-1]); j++) { ... } .  It should be AFTER the closing bracket, not before it.  You have two outputs because you are running the code twice.  If you move it outside of the loop, it will only run once and will show you the last result.

Comment: But sir, I want the code to run twice, and then show me the last result. I need that for loop for my code. I'm asking how do I make the code run twice and then print the last result?